# I am a new DM, I need help with monsters and the characters themselves

Tags: dnd-5e, new-gm

I need help dming please help me. I perfer pen and paper gaming. So please help me.

Comment: Welcome to our stack! Please take the [tour] to learn more about us and you can also visit the [help] for more information.

Comment: What questions do you have about DMing? This isn't like a typical free-form forum and instead is a true Q&A website where we need clear questions so we can provide clear answers. Once you have enough rep (20), you can join the [chat] or post on [meta] to help you narrow down a question.

Comment: Im sorry if Im just starting out. But I want to host a game but I do not know much about dungeons and dragons. As asked please help me learn more. In case you did not know, I am only under the adult age and in the teen age. So things get hard, which you must have experienced at least once in your life.

Comment: The list of questions under the [new GM tag](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-gm) may be a good starting point.

Comment: Consider also [some other RPG forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/) for suggestions to other sites that better support a discussion format and more general questions.